# How to show whether the entropy of a uniform distribution with infinite image space converges or diverges?

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, entropy, information-theory

Assuming a random variable $X$ with an infinite image space (i.e. the natural numbers $\mathbf{N}$) and the probability mass function (PMF) being the uniform distribution with PMF $P(X=n) = \frac{1}{n}$. How do I compute the entropy of that infinite uniform distribution? Does it converge or diverge?

I attempted the following but I don't know how to proceed:

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\lim_{n \to \infty} H(X) & = - \sum_{i=1}^{n} P(X=i) \, \log_{2}(P(X=i)) \\
& = - \sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{1}{n} \, \log_{2}(\frac{1}{n}) \\
& = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{log_{2}(n)}{n}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

Now, the ratio term $\frac{log_2(n)}{n} \leq 1$ because $n \geq \log_{2}(n) \;, \forall n \in \mathbf{N}$. But not sure how to proceed with this knowledge regarding convergence/divergence.

Comment: Why do you call it [uniform distribution](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/594494/how-to-show-whether-the-entropy-of-a-uniform-distribution-with-infinite-image-sp)?

Comment: Probably this answers your question: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics)#Comparison_test